# Take and download a Photo on Android

Tags: java, android, android-camera, photo

I have spent the last few hours trying to get this piece of code to successfully take a picture and download it to my phone's SD card.  For some reason it just doesn't save the photo to pictureFile.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong but if anyone could give me a hint it would be great.

```
public class PhotoTaker extends Activity {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;
    private File pictureFile;
    private CountDownTimer timer;
    public byte[] dataArray;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photoview);

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mCameraPreview);

        //Getting the actual picture
        final PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                       picturereFile = getOutputMediaFile();
                       #the pictureFils always is equal to null here and it doesn't write out anywhere
                       if (pictureFile == null){
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    dataArray = data;
                    fos.write(data);
                    fos.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d("filenotfound", null);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("ioexception", null);

                }

            }

        };


        //Adding listener
        final Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                });

/** Create a File for saving the image */

private static File getOutputMediaFile(){

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");

    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");

    return mediaFile;
}

    }
```

Here is the error in LogCat:

```
E/dalvikvm(524): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Which should be solved by this but it is still giving me the same error:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see if the safe-part is actually executed?

Comment: @Fildor what is the safe part?

Comment: Ah, sorry. The "save the picture"-part.

Comment: oh gotcha. yes I have and for some reason the picture file is always == null so I suppose it is something wrong with my getOutputMediaFile() function but I am not sure what

Comment: Now that would have been a valuable info in the first place :) Ok, I'll have another look.

Comment: There are no exceptions? Does the directory exist?

Comment: By the way: there is a "dir, filename" - Constructor. <http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File(java.io.File, java.lang.String)>

Comment: Oh, boy. The link above is broken ... I seem too stupid to use links in comments :) Another try: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html -> There the first of the public contructors.

Comment: sorry i didn't include my error. it is in there now

Comment: I'm not too sure if this is "the" error. Can you post a little more of that logcat?

Comment: Yes it is actually telling me that I am getting a null pointer error in this line:  mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture); in the button listener

Comment: Well then we have 3 possibilities: mCamera is null, mPicture is null or both. Can you check that just before calling takePicture? Just to be sure: You followed the setup-instructions on [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) ?

Comment: The logcat it seems can't reveal the problem you're experiencing, could you post a more related one?

Comment: I am working on it and I will post more soon.